# The use of Pure Korean words like 가람 [river]?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-korean, sino-korean-words

Are pure Korean words like 가람 still used in speech or writing instead of Chinese borrowings like  강 ?

Comment: “가람” is a dated and obscure word. By “pure Korean words like 가람,” do you mean native (“plain”) Korean words in general, or specifically dated, old-fashioned ones?

Comment: 가람 is no more used to mean 'river, lake'. It is sometimes used as names. If you want any example of pure Korean still used until today despite the existence of Chinese borrowings, some color names are pure Korean, like '빨강 - 적색', '노랑 - 황색', '파랑 - 청색', '검정 - 흑색', '하양 - 백색'. 날 (day-일), 달 (month-월, moon-월), 해 (year-년, sun-일) are also pure Korean,

Answer (score 1):

As others answered above, 가람 is not used in daily conversation. Sometimes it is used in names of organizations or people, as in the attached photo below (한가람고등학교).

[image: Hangaram High School]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

There used to be popular TV shows that created a trend of re-discovering pure Korean words like in 2000s, and some have become popular since then.
However, many others are still obsolete, and 가람 is one among them.
It's just that some people know 가람 means rivers, but it is rarely used for daily usages. I wouldn't expect people to understand what I mean when I say 가람.

I've seen 가람 being used for names for people or businesses though.

I think you should consider these old pure Korean words somewhat like jargons. When you say it, people may or may not understand you.

Answer (score 0):

No.

In Korea, No one uses 가람. The historical fact that 가람 means 강, is being considered like an interesting knowledge among Koreans. So there are Koreans who don't even know the word 가람. You can just understand that everyone uses 강, instead of 가람.